# Datatable in R - Data Grouping (Conditional)

Tags: r, dataframe

suppose I have the following data frame.
How can I create a new column containing the average price for the whole id, taking as calculation for the average the range=2 of each id?

```
dt<-data.frame(id=c(11,11,11,11,12,12,12),range=c(1,1,2,2,1,2,2),price=c(10,20,30,40,10,20,30))

  id range price
1 11     1    10
2 11     1    20
3 11     2    30
4 11     2    40
5 12     1    10
6 12     2    20
7 12     2    30

  id range price price2
1 11     1    10     35
2 11     1    20     35
3 11     2    30     35
4 11     2    40     35
5 12     1    10     25
6 12     2    20     25
7 12     2    30     25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A data.table solution is as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dt=as.data.table(dt)[,price2:=mean(price[range==2]),by=id]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to use the `aggregate` function. Below is an example.

```
dt<-data.frame(id=c(11,11,11,11,12,12,12),range=c(1,1,2,2,1,2,2),price=c(10,20,30,40,10,20,30))
# calculate the menas by id and range
mean_by_group <- aggregate(dt$price, list(id = dt$id, range = dt$range), mean)
# remove other results
mean_by_group <- mean_by_group[mean_by_group$range == 2, ]
# merge back to the original dataframe
dt <- merge(dt, mean_by_group[, c(1, 3)], by = c('id'))
```

And results look like this:

```
  id range price  x
1 11     1    10 35
2 11     1    20 35
3 11     2    30 35
4 11     2    40 35
5 12     1    10 25
6 12     2    20 25
7 12     2    30 25
```

Alternatively, you can use the `dplyr` and `magrittr` pacakges:

```
dt %<>% 
  group_by(id, range) %>%
  summarise(price2 = mean(price)) %>%
  filter(range == 2) %>%
  {merge(dt, .[, c(1, 3)], by = 'id')}
```

This gives you:

```
  id range price price2
1 11     1    10     35
2 11     1    20     35
3 11     2    30     35
4 11     2    40     35
5 12     1    10     25
6 12     2    20     25
7 12     2    30     25
```

Answer (score 1):

Using joins for data.table

```
setDT(dt)
x <- dt[range == 2,list(price2 = mean(price)), by = id]
dt <- dt[x, on = .(id)]
```